# Why do I keep getting "Must declare the Scalar variable "@Param1"" when performing a parameterized query in C++ using ADO?

Tags: c++, com, ado

Here is the code.
A Few notes about it.  DStr is an string class that is internal to our company.  It functions much like CString.  I can connect to the database and run non-parameterized queries.  Also this insert works fine if I do not use parameters.  The cmd->Execute statment throws an exception.  This is where I am getting the error msg from.

```
    void CEmailArchiveDatabase::TestAddUser( DStr username, DStr displayname )
{

    DStr sql = "INSERT INTO [User] (UserName, DisplayName) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)";

    _variant_t vUser;
    _variant_t vDisp; 

    vUser.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vUser.bstrVal = username.AllocSysString();
    vDisp.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vDisp.bstrVal = displayname.AllocSysString();

    _CommandPtr cmd = NULL;
    _ConnectionPtr conn = NULL;
    _ParameterPtr prm = NULL;

    DStr connStr = "driver={SQL Server};server=DEMETER\\SQLEXPRESS;database=ExtractoMundo";

    try
    {
        conn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
        cmd.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));

        if( !(conn->GetState() & adStateOpen) )
        {
            conn->ConnectionString = connStr.AllocSysString();
            conn->Open("", "", "", NULL);
            conn->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
        }   

        cmd->ActiveConnection = conn;
        cmd->CommandText = sql.AllocSysString();
        cmd->CommandType = adCmdText;

        prm = cmd->CreateParameter("@Param1", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, -1, vUser);
        cmd->Parameters->Append(prm);
        prm = cmd->CreateParameter("@Param2", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, -1, vDisp);
        cmd->Parameters->Append(prm);

        _variant_t recAff;

        cmd->Execute(&recAff, NULL, adExecuteNoRecords);

    }
    catch(_com_error &ex)
    {
        //ClearParameters();
        DStr err;
        err += PrintProviderError(conn);
        err += PrintComError(ex);
    }

    SysFreeString(vUser.bstrVal);
    SysFreeString(vDisp.bstrVal);
    SysFreeString(cmd->CommandText);
    SysFreeString(conn->ConnectionString);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO refuses to work with named parameters in dynamic queries. You have to either convert named parameters into parameter placeholders:

```
DStr sql = "INSERT INTO [User] (UserName, DisplayName) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

or use a stored procedure instead. Create the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUserInsert
  @Param1 nvarchar(50), 
  @Param2 nvarchar(50) 
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO [User] (UserName, DisplayName) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)
GO
```

and modify your code to call it:

```
DStr sql = "spUserInsert";
...
cmd->CommandType = adCmdStoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `cmd->CreateParameter(_bstr_t("Param1"), ...)` ?

The "@" is a SQL Server specific operator, it may be messing with you.

Comment: I think I see it now.  Try using adCmdStoredProc instead of adCmdText

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using adCmdStoredProc instead of adCmdText?

Comment: This is wrong because the OP is clearly not using a stored procedure.